# how to run gcov on bare metal (without file system)

Tags: c++, c, gdb, gcov, jtag

I'm running C++ on Cortex M4 and I want to start doing automated unit tests and coverage.

`gcov` writes its output files - `.gcno, .gcda` - *on the target* which is a no-go because I don't have a filesystem.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to "intercept and redirect" these writes to the PC using `gdb`?

I want to automate these tests via a Python script:

1. Get unit test from data base
2. Compile
3. Transfer to target board
4. Run
5. Redirect results to PC

Comment: So you have implement filesystem abstraction yourself. Implement `write`, `open`, `close` etc. I/O posix system calls, or whatever "gcov" utility system calls uses. What compiler, compiler options are you using? How are you compiling to the destination ar\chitecture. Without any further info, this is too broad - "is it possible to intercept _these_ writes" is vague - which writes? What have you tried? I mean, a 5 min google search results in ex. [this](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/12/26/code-coverage-for-embedded-target-with-eclipse-gcc-and-gcov/)

Comment: @KamilCuk I already knew how to do it that way. I hoped `gdb` could make it easier.

Comment: So how did you do it? You can implement the embedded I/O using semihosting and gdb should trap the calls and create the files. Looks like [this](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/06/19/gnu-code-coverage-on-embedded-target-with-eclipse-neon-and-arm-gcc-5/).

Comment: @KamilCuk I haven't done it yet. I know about semihosting but I was hoping for a uniform solution across my Linux projects and bare-metal. I guess there isn't one. I'll do semihosting.

Comment: Looks like some people are doing just that (using gcov on baremetal) https://dzone.com/articles/gnu-code-coverage-on-embedded-targets
http://allsoftwaresucks.blogspot.com/2015/05/gcov-is-amazing-yet-undocumented.html

Comment: visit [10.6 Profiling and Test Coverage in Freestanding Environments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Freestanding-Environments.html#Freestanding-Environments)

Comment: @HZ1 this is the answer. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't know gcov, thank you.

A quick look at `man gcov` showed that I had it on my system and that the following option exists:

`-t, --stdout                    Output to stdout instead of a file`

I haven't done python in a while, but you should be able to create a memory-only file, and, supposing the opened file handle is 8, use:

`gcov -t [whatever you are doing] >&8`

The -t argument tells gcov to print to the standard output instead of writing to a file, and >&8 overwrites stdout (as seen by the executed program) to be file handle 8 instead of 1 (on most unix/posix/whateveryoucallit, anyway).

That is of course in bash, which you can either invoke from python, or transcode to however you achieve this in python.

I haven't got to try it, so if it helps (or if it doesn't) make sure to leave a mark to help future readers.

Comment: This doesn’t work on bare metal because there is no stdout

Comment: No default one, but shouldn't it still allow for a user-defined file to be passed to gcov as its output file? (How does gcov react to `-t`?)

Comment: You run `gcov` on the output data files which have to be produced by the program running on bare metal

Answer (score 0):

You can try a technique called semihosting : the file I/O is then being redirected over the debug probe to the host computer.